# Search for a special character returns no results

Tags: support, search

I wanted to search for a special character (<kbd>⇞</kbd>) on Ask Different before answering to a question, but a search returned null results. An answer on [Can't find ⌃ symbol in keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123568/cant-find-symbol-in-keyboard) contains the character and should be returned.

Comment: Could you elaborate if this is somehow about how Ask Different the web ap works or are you looking to learn how to find that character on a specific software or hardware? Please edit the post with some details and we'll see about answering it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search ignores non-alphanumeric characters except where those characters have special meaning in advanced search, such as ‘[]’ for tag search. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).